# jQuery ignores if/then/else - what is wrong?

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I have a if/else situation and I don't know, what I am missing.

The Function is supposed to get the value from the selected answer(active) and show different IDs according to it. When I run it, only the if statement happens, no matter which answer is selected. That means the first ID ("#entdecker") will be shown, no matter which answer is selected.
What am I doing wrong?

```
    $('#3_gipfel').on({
      click: function(){

    var untergrund = $('.question1 .answer.active').data('answer-type');

    if (untergrund = 1) $("#entdecker").show();
    else if (untergrund = 2) $("#relaxer").show();
    else $("#grenz").show();
    }
    });
```

This is the related HTML

```
          <div class="question question1">
          <div class="col-md-4">         
          <div class="answer" data-answer-type="2">SCHNEE</div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="answer" data-answer-type="1">NEBEL</div>
          </div> 

          <div class="col-md-4">
          <div class="answer" data-answer-type="3">REGEN</div>
          </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: `if (untergrund = 1)` is setting the value of `untergrund`, not comparing it. You need to use either `==` (standard comparison) or `===` (type-sensitive comparison).

Comment: jQuery doesn't do comparisons, javascript does

Comment: == was the solution.. thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `==` or `===` for comparison. One `=` is for assignment.

```
$('#3_gipfel').on({
  click: function(){

var untergrund = $('.question1 .answer.active').data('answer-type');

if (untergrund == 1) $("#entdecker").show();
else if (untergrund == 2) $("#relaxer").show();
else $("#grenz").show();
}
});
```

Comment: don't forget to mark the question as the answer by clicking the check mark if this answered your question. Welcome to StackOverflow!